# mysql ambiguous column titles

Tags: php, mysql, database, search

Okay so i have a search code that looks into two tables. I know that the ambiguity comes from the fact that there is a column "title" in both tables (tables named disc track).

now my fix was this.

```
$query="SELECT * FROM  disc, track WHERE Artist LIKE '%$trimmed%' OR disc.Title LIKE 

'%$trimmed%' OR Year LIKE '%$trimmed%' OR Genre LIKE '%$trimmed%' LIMIT 0, 30";
```

.

```
 Notice: Undefined index: disc.Title in C:\xampp\htdocs\search.php on line 61
```

I have been searching everywhere, and anywhere I go it says that that code is correct. but whenever I run through a search it says disc.Title doesn't exist (when i only search one of the tables it can find Title)

any ideas?

Comment: One thought is you may need to repeat the LIKE statement. Could you include the specific error?

Comment: It's possible that your SQL server is configured to use case sensitive column names.

Comment: How does artist relate to track?

Comment: I keep formatting your code, and you keep un-formatting it. Do you have something against, our eyes?

Comment: Undefined index is due to MySQL server not finding the column name. Might be due to case. Ambiguous column is due to two tables having the same column name. For the latter use table name prefixes or replacement name.

Comment: OP, please do be careful when editing that you don't overwrite good edits - if you refresh your browser prior to hitting the edit button, you should get the latest version. cc: @phpNoOb

Answer (score 2):

run `$query="SELECT * FROM disc, track WHERE Artist LIKE '%$trimmed%'"` does it work?

it is the `OR disc.Title` in  that is throwing you off.

you need to complete the `disk.Title` expression. `OR disc.Title LIKE '%$trimmed%'`

also as far as running SQL goes, you should explicitly write your joins.

```
SELECT * 
FROM disc
INNER JOIN track
    ON disk.id = track.disk_id
WHERE (
    [disk or track?].Artist LIKE '%$trimmed%' 
    OR disc.Title LIKE '%$trimmed%'
)
```

Comment: the query without title works. the full line was updated in my question. I don't understand the INNER JOIN in your code, but i implemented it and it does not work.

Comment: run `DESCRIBE disk;` and paste the output. see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT d.*, t.* FROM  disc d, track t WHERE t.Artist LIKE '%$trimmed%' OR d.Title LIKE '%$trimmed%' OR Year LIKE '%$trimmed%' OR t.Genre LIKE '%$trimmed%' LIMIT 0, 30
```

You should use the table information / prefix for all join and select items.

Comment: that just gave me more errors. the table prefix is not working.